# Wii U not recognizing the adapter + ethernet cable

Tags: technical-issues, wii-u

I had my Wii U turned off, put the adapter in and then the ethernet cable. But, whenever I go into wired connection it tells me to plug in the adapter even though it's already in, whats the problem? (The adapter is an official nintendo product.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest getting a new Lan-Adapter ([this one](https://store.nintendo.com/ng3/us/po/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?categoryNav=true&navAction=jump&navCount=0&atg.multisite.remap=false&productId=prod10279&categoryId=cat10012)).

Make sure to follow those steps ([How to Connect a Wii LAN Adapter to the Wii U](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1668/~/how-to-connect-a-wii-lan-adapter-to-the-wii-u)) properly.

If that does not resolve your issue, you should get in contact with Nintendo Support, if you have not done so yet.